# XML refresh of table data in copiedVB worksheet refreshes all instances of table

Tags: xml, excel, salesforce, metadata, vba

Thanks for any insights, (and I apologize in advance for the long post)

I regularly have to create a Configuration workbook for clients based on the metadata configured in their Salesforce.com Org (cloud installation).  Clients prefer that this workbook be an Excel file.

The Salesforce.com MetaData API can be used to create handy xml based '.object' files for each Salesforce.com object in the org, which contain the necessary metadata that needs to end up in Excel.

I have already created an Excel workbook containing a single worksheet which serves as my 'template' for storing the metadata for a given .object file.

I have created 3 separate tables in this worksheet, to store Custom Field, Record Type, and Validation metadata for the object.

I have created a single .XSD file that populates all three tables in this worksheet with the metadata from a given .object file.

I would like a VB macro to use this worksheet, tables, and .XSD file to loop through a list of .object files performing the following tasks:

1. Copy the existing template worksheet - Solved
2. Rename the new copy with part of the .object filename - Solved
3. ImportXML using the .XSD file and existing tables (populate the new worksheet tables with the current iteration's .object file metadata)
4. Iterate to the next .object file and repeat until each has it's own tab

NOTE:I will create this list of .object separately for each Configuration Workbook, probably by scanning a directory

Major difficulty:
I can copy the template worksheet and rename it, but when I run the import XML for the new worksheet, it's overwriting the data in every instance of the tables (across all worksheets).

What this means is that I'll end up with all the worksheets that I need, but they will all contain the same .object file's metadata from the final import performed, instead of the .object specific metadata appropriate to each worksheet.

Questions:

1. Is this architecture appropriate for the problem?
2. Since I'm copying the original worksheet (it has non-table data and formatting that I'd like to preserve) to create each additional, I assume that it must be copying the same table to each sheet.

1. Is there a way to decouple these copied tables from each other and still maintain my .XSD databindings?
2. Am I better off deleting the table and re-building a new one from scratch in each worksheet?
3. Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Here is my Code:

```
Sub newObject(fileName As String)
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim myMap As XmlMap
    Dim schemaPath As String
    folderPath = "C:\...\objects - QA\"
    schemaPath = "mySchema.XSD"
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    'Name the new copied sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 7) & ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Count
    'Add a named XmlMap to the collection
    Set myMap = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(folderPath & schemaPath)
    Call ImportXmlFromFile(folderPath & schemaPath, folderPath, fileName)

End Sub

Sub ImportXmlFromFile(myMap As String, myFolder As String, myFile As String)
   ' buildFieldsListS (myMap)
     ThisWorkbook.XmlMaps(myMap).Import (myFolder + myFile)

    Exit Sub
MyErr:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry that my ordered lists are showing up as code, but this wouldn't post my question until I Control-K'd it.

Comment: You say "I can copy the template worksheet and rename it, but when I run the import XML for the new worksheet, it's overwriting the data in every instance of the tables (across all worksheets)."  This code has a bug in it.  Show it to us and we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I should have said "probably has a bug".  Now, I'm not so sure ...

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I think that the ActiveSheet.Copy is somehow including the same instance of a table in the resulting worksheet or something similar.  I think that I need to decouple the tables in each sheet from each other, or build a new table from scratch somehow.

Comment: I suspect it's the XmlMap, not the table that's the problem (see my post below).

Comment: Oops, wait a second.  Are all of these object files in the same folder?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Yes, all of the object files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

XmlMaps are a Workbook-wide resource, I suspect that when you open a new object file, but give it the same, schema and rootname as an exisiting XmlMap in the same workbook, it thinks that you are trying to update the prior/existing map, instead of create and add a new one.

I think that you need to copy the template sheet to the New Workbook first, then create and import the new XmlMap in that new workbook.

---

Alternatively, try it with the following changes:

```
Sub newObject(fileName As String)
    On Error Goto MyERR

    ' ... '

    'Add a named XmlMap to the collection'
    Set myMap = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(folderPath & schemaPath)
    Call ImportXmlFromFile(myMap, folderPath, fileName)

    Exit Sub
MyErr:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly

End Sub

Sub ImportXmlFromFile(myMap As XmlMap, ByVal myFolder As String, myFile As String)
     myMap.Import myFolder & myFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the help.  Unfortunately, this is the first thing that I tried.  It successfully adds a new map to the workbook, but the results are exactly the same. I switched to the original code I posted above so that I could stop deleting all the Mapping files that I was creating during testing.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that I'm receiving a Subscript out of Range error when my ImportXMLFromFile sub runs myMap.Import(myFolder & myFile).

Comment: When I create a new XML Map and I simply run:
 Call ImportXmlFromFile("CustomObject_Map1", "C:\SFDC ANT Projects\CCE\Production Data for Config Workbook\objects - QA\", "Account.object")


I get the following error:  "Run-time error '1004':  No data was imported because no elements have been mapped.  Use Range.XPath.SetValue to map XML elements onto the worksheet."

Also, when viewing the source pane on the right-sidebar, it's clear that the new map has been created, but it's also clear that none of the mappings of the schema data onto the table on the main worksheet exist.

Comment: Error 1004 is the generic error that Excel throws when VBA has an unhandled error.  Add some error-handling and use MsgBox with err.Description to see what the actual error in VBA is.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm brand new to VB, I'm not sure how to implement the error handling that you've described.  

The run-time error above is fairly specific, was it hard to decipher that quoted text below was part of the error?  Or was it not detailed enough?

"No data was imported because no elements have been mapped. Use Range.XPath.SetValue to map XML elements onto the worksheet."

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I added the error handling you included in your above (from "Exit Sub" to "vbOKOnly" into my ImportXmlFromFile Sub and it's showing me the same error text that I posted in the earlier comment.  I have updated my original code above so that you can see what I did.  Is this the right place to put the code?

Comment: You need an `On Error Goto MyErr:` at the beginning of the routine.

Comment: Thanks for all the help with this.  

I ended up digging up a solution that: 
1) imports the xml and makes a copy of the worksheet
2) deletes the table from the copied worksheet
3) pastes the data (but not the whole table) into the now tableless copy
4) creates a table from the pasted data.

This isn't what I set out to do, but it's gotten me around the roadblock of needing to disassociate the various copies of the XML table from each other.

I really appreciate all the help though!

Thanks, 
-Dan